# Is it possible to convert cli output (string) to a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have this original string being output from a CLI application.

```
ScriptSessions = 101 [default: 100, range: 0-500]
```

The output keys can have different names, values can be strings and sometimes include a range like value.  I've written a small function to cleanup the string like this.

```
differentName:value,default:100,range:0-500
```

Is it possible to somehow convert this string to a dictionary?  So a call like this var[default] would then return 100?  I have created function to grep this second string but it will be slow.  The current function is expected to be called for each key value pair with over 1000 tests (Possibly 3000 to 4000 times). If I could load a dictionary once and then query the dictionary for the result I'd expect it to be much faster.  Some strings returned by the CLI have some 8 to 10 key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, provided the string respects the pairs 'key:value' separated by commas, and `s` is your string: `{w.split(':')[0]: w.split(':')[1] for w in s.split(',')}`

How it works: the string is split using the commas:

```
>>> s = 'differentName:value,default:100,range:0-500'
>>> s.split(',')
['differentName:value', 'default:100', 'range:0-500']
```

And then each substring from this list is split, using the semicolons, as key: value pairs of a dictionary:

```
>>> s = 'differentName:value,default:100,range:0-500'
>>> {w.split(':')[0]: w.split(':')[1] for w in s.split(',')}
{'differentName': 'value', 'default': '100', 'range': '0-500'}
```

As to whether this will be more efficient this way than the other way, I cannot tell.

If this might be useful, there's an [intspan package available on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/intspan/) to handle int spans.